# Django: Quickly deal with adding non-nullable field

Tags: python, django, django-models

When developing models I quite often get the non-nullable field error when running `makemigrations`:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to randommodel without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

Almost all the time when I get this error I'm quite happy to delete the data in that table (it's normally only a couple of test entries while developing) and it would be more efficient to just delete it rather than determine what a suitable default would be.

However currently I don't have a suitable method for doing this and end up flushing the database and/or deleting the migrations, which is pretty heavy handed but works.

What's the best way to delete the data just in that model/table to remove the error? (Would it be via shell/shell_plus?)

Model:

```
class RandomModel(models.Model):
    user_details = JSONField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you have deleted all the records in that table, when running `makemigrations`, you'll be asked to provide default values again. This is because you're making a new migration file for an existing table.

One solution I can think of is to tell Django that you're starting that `app_name` over again by running `migrate app_name zero`. This will unapply all migration files that have ever been applied to your database.

Then delete all the migration files in your `app_name`. And run `makemigrations` again. This would create a new initial migration file. Then you just apply it to your database with `migrate`.

As you've said you don't mind deleting your data. This is even better. You don't have to even delete any record. It will just create a new table with the same name with all the new fields and with 0 record.

Comment: when deleting migration files, I also had to delete migration files in any other apps that referenced that particular app.

Comment: You didn't state that there's any reference to your model. But I'm happy that you find the solution for that.